# Is it possible to compare one set of data with another set of data within +-5%

Tags: r, database

I am wondering if there is a method in R to compare one set of data with another set of data, to see these two sets of data are close to each other, the second set of data are with + - 5% for the whole data set. the second set of data has 5% error and I would to include it in the data set. Both sets of data measured the same parameter along with times. I can ignore times here and just compare two sets of data.

I tried to find a method online but I couldn't.

My main question here is how to express the second data set in R. 
For example:

```
data1 = c(10,20,30,40,50)
data2 = c(11,25,31,44,52)
```

But how to put the +-5% in `data2` using R code?

I know t-test, ANOVA can be used to compare the data sets. Maybe other method is better

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `all.equal(data1, data2)` could be an option but this scenario is a best candidate for t-test approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some of these basics. in R you can do operations on vectors which apply d to corresponding elements.

```
data1 = c(10,20,30,40,50)
data2 = c(11,25,31,44,52)

diff = (data2 - data1) / data1
diff
# [1] 0.10000000 0.25000000 0.03333333 0.10000000 0.04000000

diff < .05
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

any(diff < .05)
# [1] TRUE
```